# Is every $S^1$ knot orientable?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

let $K$ be an $S^1$ knot, i.e., $K$ is a homeomorphic copy of the "standard" $S^1$ 
living in $\mathbb R^3$ ). I am trying to see if $K$ is orientable.
This is what I have:
1) If the map sending
$S^1$ to $K$ is a diffeomorphism, we are done. Diffeomorphisms are either orientation
preserving or orientation reversing. Besides , a diffeomorphism would give rise to a vector space (tangent space) isomorphism, and then the image tangent space describes an orientation.

2) If the embedding is not a diffeomorphism, just a homeomorphism.
Then maybe we could see what happens with the image of the top (co) homology with
coefficients in $\mathbb Z$. The induced maps on (co)homology are isomorphisms. So the
top class, the orientation/fundamental class cannot be mapped to the $0$ class. But it
will be mapped (I think) to a subgroup of $\mathbb Z$ , meaning to {$ n \mathbb Z$}. 
Am I on the right track?
Thanks.

Comment: The knot is, by definition, a subspace homeomorphic to $S^1$. Since orientability of manifolds is invariant under homeos, then it is enough to ask if $S^1$ is orientable. And it is,

Comment: Thanks, but I am sort of trying to show this, or at least I would like to see a proof of this. Do the arguments in my post work? Why, e.g., cant we have the top class --given by $\mathbb Z$ -- be sent to a proper subgroup of $\mathbb Z$. Or, if the embedding is not a homeomorphism, cant $df$ have non-trivial zeros?

Comment: The notion of orientability of a manifold doesn't depend on where it's embedded. $S^1$ is always orientable, everywhere, all the time. If you mean something else that does depend on an embedding, you should spell out what that is.

Comment: But what prevents a homeomorphism from sending the fundamental class to some proper subgroup? Or what prevents us from having a (differentible) non-diffeomorphism f from having non-trivial zeros in $df_p$? I am sort of trying to see how the homeomorphism gives rise to an orientation in the knot.

Comment: Homeomorphisms, by definition, have inverses, so they have to induce isomorphisms on homology. If you're working with homeomorphisms you should work with a notion of orientability that doesn't require a smooth structure to describe.

Comment: Right, you could argue that a homeomorphism induces an isomorphism on homology too, I guess. I am using two separate cases, one for diffeomorphisms and one for plane homeomorphisms. But I guess then even a weak homotopy equivalence would preserve orientation. Is this the weakest condition?

Comment: Weak homotopy equivalences do not preserve orientability. Not even homotopy equivalences.  For an example, consider a cilinder and a moebius strip.

Comment: But dont weak homotopy equivalences give rise to isomorphisms in homology? Then the top class $\mathbb Z$ must be sent to the fundamental class, no?

Comment: @Quiaochu Yuan: Is it know whether the integers are isomorphic to one of its subgroups? If they are, then the orientation class may map isomorphically to a non-orientation class. Maybe the isomorphism takes $\mathbb Z$ to $2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user211339: Consider reading about the definition of orientation for topological manifolds, e.g. http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Orientation_of_manifolds. Given the right definition, you will have no trouble proving that orientability is a topological invariant for all manifolds. Of course, for the circle, it can be done much easier.

Comment: But before you read up on orientations you **must** decide whether $\mathbb Z$ is isomorphic to one of its subgroups or not!